# What is this IC marked "26384533TVO"?

Tags: microcontroller, identification

What is the microcontroller (I assume) at the top of this picture, marked `26384533TVO`?

This picture is from the inside of a wireless sensor, where an accelerometer and radio are also present. The device appears to be a 16 lead QFN, likely 3 mm x 3 mm.

[image]
<sub>(source: [staticflickr.com](https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7068/6971469407_99cd296490.jpg))</sub>

Comment: It very well may be a custom ASIC.

Comment: Possible, but, this is coming from a low investment startup (greengoose.com). Everything else is off-the-shelf.

Comment: That's a Freescale logo.

Comment: It's 8-DFN, not 16-QFN, no?  Freescale doesn't have part marking info for their small microcontrollers that I can find.  Still, they only make a few in DFN8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like it could be a generic knockoff of the 8453 accelerometer.  Freescale's [MMA8453Q](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=MMA8453Q) is in a similar package.

Comment: 'doh. I'd assumed that was the micro, in fact the other chip must be. So, now I have a new question...

Comment: already anticipated the new question, and seeing what I can dig up

Comment: @TevoD I'm curious how you came to that conclusion. Not questioning, just wondering how you figured that one.

Comment: @Michael, I seem to have a knack for finding things?  Conclusion is a stronger word that I used, as I indicated it could be the right part.  This was based on the information provided.  I checked each part of the part number and searched for likely possibilities.  Joby indicated that an accelerometer was present, so this was a close match.  The decoupling cap C18 on pin 14 and NC on 15-16 are consistent with the spec for the accelerometer, so I floated it as an answer.

Comment: @TevoD In other words "Elementary my dear Watson."

Comment: I think it was the lure of TVO part being close to TEVO that made him obsess over finding it...